# AppleScript: Is it possible to get iTunes current-playing song timing info by AppleScript?

Tags: plugins, applescript, itunes

I know it's possible to write AppleScript to get tag metadata about current song, e.g., artist name, album, etc.

Would it be possible to get the playback position as well?

Comment: BTW You can open iTunes with the AppleScript-Editor to see it's scripting dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "iTunes" to get player position
```